# JavaScript code behind in c#

Tags: javascript, c#

I have the following code in my cs file.

```
private bool ValidateFirst()
{
    StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder();

    sb2.Append(@"<script language='javascript'> var bContinue = true;");
    sb2.Append(@"bContinue = confirm(");
    sb2.Append("'some text here'");
    sb2.Append(@");");

    sb2.Append("if (bContinue) {");
    sb2.Append(this.Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(this, "OKFinal"));
    sb2.Append("}</script>");

    this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page.GetType(), "ConfirmDialog", sb2.ToString());

    return false;
}
```

So what I wanted here is to display a confirm pop up on the page. The `sb2.ToString()` is working when I tested it on JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2rbcsvh6/ (_doPostBack event will not work) but on my application, it won't display. The code is inside the screen controller action command.

```
protected void screenController_ActionCommand(object sender, Web.Controls.CancelCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == ScreenController.OkCommand)
    {
        // this is the method that contains the script
        if (ValidateFirst)
        {
            this.Save();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Using your JSFiddle, I get a JavaScript error `ReferenceError: __doPostBack is not defined`.

Comment: @UweKeim that'll be because it's not running under an ASP.NET site

Comment: But i got a popup says asd, i am using Google chrome browser

Comment: @UweKeim - because JSFiddle is not running on the ASP.NET application. But still, the confirm should be displayed.

Comment: @ArunPrasanth check your console though, you will have the same error.

Comment: I know, @James - That's just to falsify the authors "it is working on JSFiddle" claim.

Comment: @UweKeim sometimes you need to read between the lines when people write questions, I got what the OP was referring to and understood that `__doPostBack` wasn't going to work in a JSFiddle (the OP has actually mentioned this in his question). The point of the fiddle was just to give us an idea of what the expected JS would look like (although, arguably they could have just written that in the question).

Comment: @James yes it shows the error

Comment: @Gerald where is this code called?

Comment: @James - the code is called inside the screen controller action command. Basically before doing a Save

Comment: @Gerald from an ASP.NET WebForms perspective, I have no idea what a "*screen controller action command*" is.

Comment: What is `Beeline.Web`? This question gets unclearer by every edit.

Comment: Same as this, we just have our own framework https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.commandeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is by the time you embed the JS the page has already been loaded and rendered. You need to either run your code before the page has loaded i.e. `Page_Load` or alternatively wrap your JS in a function which you can then invoke from the client.

Comment: @Gerald It's also not possible to do `if (ValidateFirst()) { Save() }` if the `ValidateFirst` portion of that is relying on this client side code - you can't flick between client side and server side code like that.

Comment: @JamesThorpe - I have a separate code to handle that case. Thanks btw.